# Extending the identity table with enum column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working in a web application using ASP.Net. I'm trying to add new column with enum type to AspNetUsers called AccountStatus (Active, InActive, Expired and Locked).

I'm following a tutorial for "Adding properties to Identity Users" so  i did the following:

In Register.cshtml.cs file, i added the line:

```
public enum AccountStatus { Active,InActive,Expired,Locked}
```

And I created "ApplicationUser" class which is inherited from IdentityUsers as following:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
namespace RegisterTest.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public enum AccountStatus { Active, InActive, Expired, Locked }
    }
}
```

Then, I added the DbSet here:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RegisterTest.Models;

namespace RegisterTest.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then, I added the migration and update the database but what i actually got is a new field called "Discriminator"

Can anyone help me on this? I don't know if i'm missing any concept or doing something wrong?
I need to add the AccountStatus as enum Field to the Identity user table.
Please any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that the application rebuilt before you generated the migration? Can you include the migration this change generated?

Comment: Yes it is rebuild before migration. The migration has just adding new field called "discriminator"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the conversion for your enum within your DbContext as such:

```
        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Wine>()
        .Property(e => e.WineVariantId)
        .HasConversion<int>();
```

This code was taken from https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/50375357/how-to-create-a-table-corresponding-to-enum-in-ef-core-code-first-. It looks like there is more to setting up an enum to be code first than simply defining it in the model.